# Converting a Table to a Dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I feel like this is a simple task, and there may be a built in method to doing this (but I can't find it if there is). I would like to be able to take a table and convert it into a structured Dataset. Preferably, I'd like it to be generic for any number of columns and rows. Lets assume that I have a table `Tbl` and a list of column names `Col` and that `Tbl` and `Col` have the same number of columns.

```
Col={"ColA","ColB","ColC"};
Tbl={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

For Interest, I might also like it to handle an optional list of row names `RowNames`.

```
RowNames={"Row1","Row2","Row3"};
```

Please let me know if you can come up with a simple way to do this

The final desired format would be something like this:

```
Result = Dataset[{<|"ColA" -> 1, "ColB" -> 2, "ColC" -> 3|>,
                  <|"ColA" -> 4, "ColB" -> 5, "ColC" -> 6|>,
                  <|"ColA" -> 7, "ColB" -> 8, "ColC" -> 9|>}]
```

or this if it used RowNames:

```
Dataset[<|"Row1" -> <|"ColA" -> 1, "ColB" -> 2, "ColC" -> 3|>,
          "Row2" -> <|"ColA" -> 4, "ColB" -> 5, "ColC" -> 6|>,
          "Row3" -> <|"ColA" -> 7, "ColB" -> 8, "ColC" -> 9|>|>]
```

Comment: `Row` is a protected built-in symbol in Mathematica, you can't use it as a variable. Please write down the output you are trying to achieve, i.e. what the final `Association` should look like.

Comment: Well, the obvious way is `Dataset@AssociationThread[row, AssociationThread[col, #] & /@ tbl]` ... I'm waiting to see better ways as I find this too long.

Comment: I made corresponding edits. Thanks!

Comment: The best (bulletproof) way to avoid conflicts with builtin symbols is to start your own symbol names with lowercase letters.

Comment: this is pretty long too: `Dataset[tbl][All, AssociationThread[col, Range[Length[col]]]]`

Comment: There is a resource function for this. I looked at its code, and it is basically the same answer presented here. [DatasetWithHeaders](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DatasetWithHeaders)

Comment: Also, the answer provided by @Szabolcs (mapping of `AssociationThread`) is much faster (by an order of magnitude+) than the alternative presented here or in the resource function which use sort of a dataset subquery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might as well give an answer (might not be the ideal solution):

```
col = {"ColA", "ColB", "ColC"};
row = {"Row1", "Row2", "Row3"};
tbl = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

Dataset[AssociationThread[row, tbl]][All, AssociationThread[col, Range[Length[col]]]]
```

[image: dataset]

Comment: I actually like @Szabolcs' answer in the comments much better